# Using a UIProgressBar to display status of a download

Tags: ios, download, progress, documents, uiprogressbar

Does anyone have a link to a good tutorial about using a UIProgessBar in iOS to display the status of a download? I wouldn't have a problem even taking the total download size and inserting an if statement that states if (downloaded "x" megabytes), then add 0.1 to the progress bar. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ASIHTTPRequest

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained by [its author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820712/108622). You may want to look at [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this up into managable pieces. First look into how to do downloading. Something I expect would invole a trip into multitreading. Then once you have some basic code doing that, look into dealing with interface objects from background threads. This will give you the info you need as to how to best update displays.